# What is the default start and end values in dHtmlx gantt time scale

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx, gantt-chart

I am using DHtmlxGantt. In my smaple gantt chart I have some tasks.

My question is "What is the default start and end values of time scale in a DHtmlxGantt chart".

I know that we can set these boundary values using `gantt.config.start_date` and `gantt.config.end_date`. But without setting that values explicitly, what would be the default start and end boundaries.

When I tried to read the same properties `gantt.config.start_date` and `gantt.config.end_date`, without setting them explicitly, the result is coming as `undefined`.

Could you please suggest any solution to get the default start and end values in the gantt chart time scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If date range is not specified explicitly, gantt uses the dates of the loaded tasks and adds some offset before the first and after the last task in scale.
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_scale_offset_minimal_config.html

You can get a displayed date range programmatically using gantt.getState() method http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_getstate.html